# Closed form for the recurrence T(n) = T(n-1) + n²

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

Given the following recurrence:

$$ T(n) = T(n-1) + n^2$$

How can I prove it to be $O(n^3)$ with the substitution method? The $O(n^3)$ guess derives from the fact that at every step of the recursion we pay $n^2$ and we have $n$ steps of recursion therefore having: $n \times n^2 = n^3$.

I would even expect this to be $\Theta(n^3)$, but I can't even prove $O(n^3)$.

I tried with the guess:

$$ T(n) \leq n^3 + n^2 \cdot c_1 + n \cdot c_2 + c_3 $$

but that yields:

$$ T(n) \leq n^3 + n^2 \cdot (3 + c_1) + n \cdot (c_2 - 2c_1 -1) + (c_1 - 1 - c_2 + c_3) $$

which yields:

1. $c_1 = c_1 + 3$
2. $c_2 = c_2 - 2c_1 - 1$
3. $c_3 = c_1 - 1 - c_2 + c_3$

But even from the very first ($c_1 = c_1 + 3$) we find that no $c_1$, $c_2$ or $c_3$ satisfy the equations.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If $T(n)$ is $O(n^3)$, then with a coefficient to $n^3$:

$$ 
T(n) \leq n^3 c_3 + n^2 c_2 + n c_1 + c_0
$$
So, expanding $T(n+1)$:
$$\begin{align*}
T(n + 1) &\leq (n + 1)^3 c_3 + (n + 1)^2 c_2 + (n + 1) c_1 + c_0 \\
T(n) + (n + 1)^2 &\leq n^3 c_3 + 3n^2 c_3 + 3n c_3 + c_3 + n^2 c_2 + 2n c_2 + c_2 + n c_1 + c_1 + c_0\end{align*} $$

Leading us to:

$$
T(n) \leq n^3 c_3 + n^2 (3c_3 + c_2 - 1) + n (3c_3 + 2c_2 + c_1 - 2) + c_3 + c_2 + c_1 + c_0 - 1
$$

Therefore:

1. $ c_3 = c_3 $
2. $ c_2 = 3c_3 + c_2 - 1 $
3. $ c_1 = 3c_3 + 2c_2 + c_1 - 2 $
4. $ c_0 = c_3 + c_2 + c_1 + c_0 - 1$

Solving:

$$\begin{align}
c_3 &= 1/3 \\
c_2 &= 1/2 \\
c_1 &= 1/6
\end{align} \\
T(n) \leq n^3/3 + n^2/2 + n/6 + c_0 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} + c_0
$$

Comment: I'm not sure why you are expanding $T(n+1)$ though.

Comment: @Jefffrey why not? Personal preference for $-$ over $+$, I suppose.

Comment: @Jefffrey Ok, I'll bite. What would you do instead, and how would it be better?

Comment: You have a typo: $T(n) = O(n^3)$ rather than $T(n) = O(n)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus oh, yes, sorry about that.

Comment: Well, as far as I know math is not about general preceference. The recurrence has $T(n - 1)$ as the recursive step. I'm not sure how solving $T(n + 1)$ will help in any way.

Comment: @Jefffrey sure, it has $T(n-1)$ in the recursive step. What of it? I can replace $n$ with $y+1$ and get an equivalent recursion, and expanding $(y+1)^3$ frees me from juggling the signs involved in $(n-1)^3$.

Comment: Yes, but that would involve converting then back to $n$ with $y = n - 1$, which is not something you are doing. As far as I can see you are solving a completely different recursion.

Comment: @Jefffrey if we need that much rigour, it's not too hard to see that, from the second inequality onwards, $n$ is actually $y$. So, in the last inequality, replace $y$ with $n-1$, then add $n^2$ to both sides arrive at the same thing in terms of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Expanding the recurrence, we get that
$$ T(n) = n^2 + (n-1)^2 + \cdots + 1^2 + T(0). $$
It is known that
$$\sum_{m=1}^n m^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \Theta(n^3).$$

Comment: Does that mean that it's not possible to use the substitution method here?

Comment: Since there is an exact formula, you can definitely use the substitution method. You must have made a mistake in your calculation above.